# How can I take screenshot in BlackArch Linux?

Tags: arch-linux, screenshot, screencasting

Which program can I use to take a screen cap or take video of my screen?
Maybe it's a simple (silly) question, but I can't find a good solution.

Comment: Maybe I need to write a program? If I need, please, help me. 
Explain to me, please. I think that i can understand well explanation.
Unfortunately, I'm not experienced enough.

Comment: What happens when you press <kbd>Print Screen</kbd>?

Comment: Nothing, maybe happens something, but I don't know how to open the file manager.

Comment: I have to agree with [amethystAnt](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/114853/amethystant) on using KSnapshot. I'm not familiar enough with BlackArch, but it looks like it uses fluxbox so right click on the desktop to pull up your program launcher.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23635/discussion-between-z7-zzz-and-sailorcire).

Comment: No, it not helped to me

Answer (score 1):

There are several programs for that purpose. I recommend KSnapshot, which has more options, or you can use scrot

Comment: Thank's :) How can I install this & same programms for this distribution? Sorry for such trivial question, I only recently decided to deepen in Arch, before used only Debian and Ubuntu. Wich terminal xterm?

Comment: What do you mean by "How is this program for the distribution?"? If you mean where is the package, I don't know how much is BlackArch compatible with Arch (which I use), but try $pacman -Ss ksnapshot

Comment: Heh.. I was hoping that people here will be wiser and kinder than elsewhere.. But I had been wrong.. My apologies for concern, I'll continue on way of trial and errors ..